# Ключи в словаре дублируются при записи через json.dumps

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, словари, dict

Данная проблема была у меня несколько раз, каждый раз я находил решение, но потом опять сталкивался с этим. В этот раз я уже не могу понять, в чем проблема.
Буду рад если вы подскажете.

Делаю чат-бота, записываю данные о пользователях в файл, оттуда же читаю данные один раз во время запуска бота. Пользуюсь библиотекой json, python3.

Ключи начинают дублироваться после первой же записи в файл.
Вот как я читаю из файла:

```py
def reloadz():
    global users, payments
    try:
        with open(path + 'data.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            datz = json.loads(f.read())

            users = datz['users']
            payments = datz['payments']

            print(datz)
    except:
        with open(path + 'data.json', 'w') as f:
            f.write(json.dumps({'users': {}, 'payments': []}))
        users = {}
        payments = []

reloadz()
```

Во время работы бота, я изменяю переменные `users` и `payments`. В конце каждой итерации я делаю запись обратно в файл:

```py
with open(path + 'data.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(json.dumps({'users': users, 'payments': payments}))
```

В итоге, после первой же итерации, в файле появляется два одинаковых ключа в словаре. Вот пример того, что получается в файле:

```
{"users": {"603660417": {"sub": false, "current_menu": "main"}, "603660417": {"sub": true, "current_menu": "sub"}}, "payments": [16019644137]}
```

Думаю уже полдня, не знаю, что делать. Подскажите!

Comment: Я бы предположил, что один из Ваших `"603660417"` -- это число, а другой -- строка, потому что в словаре одинаковых ключей быть не должно. В качестве доказательства, я попробовал такое: `test = {'1': 1, 1: 1} ¶ open('test', 'w').write(json.dumps(test))`. В файле test записано: `{"1": 1, "1": 1}`. Если же только что созданный так файл прочитать (`data = json.loads(open('test').read())`), то `print(data)` даёт вывод в консоли `{'1': 1}`

Comment: @EurobeatIntensifies Да, думаю так и есть. Да и я помню, что раньше эта проблема тоже была связанна с типами.
Но вроде, пересмотрел код, я нигде не добавляю в users str(id)... Если хотите, могу отправить весь код.

Comment: Как я понимаю, это стандарт json: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4627 а фраза из пункта `2.2.  Objects`, дословно `A name is a string.` означает, что ключ должен быть строкой, т.е. независимо от Ваших действий он станет строкой. Другой вопрос -- как питон дружит с этим стандартом. Судя по моему примеру из предыдущего комментария, в этой части -- поведение со стандартом совпадает. К сожалению, я в этой теме не специалист, поэтому не знаю, насколько точно стандарты применяются

Answer (score 4):

Проблема заключается в том, что в качестве ключей массива users используются как числовое, так и строковое представление user_id.

## Алгоритм приводящий к проблеме

1. Числовое представление используется Вами где-то в коде при записи в словарь `users` данных о пользователе.
2. Словарь `users` сохраняется в файл через `json.dumps`, который по стандарту JSON преобразует числовое представление в строковое.
3. Функция `reloadz` считывает данные о `users` из файла, преобразуя их в словарь с помощью `json.loads`. При этом ключи уже имеют строковое представление.
4. Повторяется шаг 1 и добавляет пользователь с числовым значением идентификатора. Теперь в словаре этот пользователь содержится 2 раза. (Строковый ключ, из-за логики работы библиотеки json, согласно стандарту JSON. А также числовой ключ, который только что был добавлен Вами где-то в коде).
5. Словарь `users` сохраняется в файл через `json.dumps`. Теперь в файле два пользователя с одинаковым ключом (строковый ключ и числовой ключ преобразованный в строковый).

## Решение проблемы

*Вариант 1.*
После чтения словаря `users` преобразовывать все ключи в числа.

```
users = {int(k):v for k, v in datz['users'].items()}
```

*Вариант 2.*
Везде использовать только строковое представление идентификатора.

```
users[str(id)] = {**user_info}
user_info = users[str(id)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция reloads() за одну операцию только считывает данные, в случае проблем с файлом или форматом в файле, просто удаляет все данные и оставляет только пустые users и payments. Вот пример кода который считывает данные и записывает обратно, как должно быть судя по описанию:

```
import json
import os

path = ''


def reloadz():
    global users, payments
    try:
        with open(os.path.join(path, 'data.json'), 'r', encoding='utf-8') as f:  # для исключения проблем с путями к файлам
            datz = json.load(f)  # оптимизация встроенная в модуль json

            users = datz['users']
            payments = datz['payments']

            print(datz)

            with open(os.path.join(path, 'data.json'), 'w') as f:
                json.dump({'users': {}, 'payments': []}, f)  # оптимизация встроенная в модуль json
            users = {}
            payments = []
    except Exception as e:  # для упрощенного поиска проблем, если надо игнорить одну ошибку, лучше её промисать конкретно (BufferError или подобное)
        print(e)


reloadz()
```

Comment: Проблема была не в этом, а в том, что при записи обратно в файл, получается два идентичных ключа.