json.dumps при sort_keys=true не умеет сравнивать числа и строки
Мне нужно сдампить данные в json (ключами могут быть и числа, и строки, может быть вложенные словари/списки). Хочется также поддерживать сортировку ключей.
Проблема в том, что код
import json
print(json.dumps({1: 1, '2': '2'}, sort_keys=True))

падает с ошибкой
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'

Причины падения очевидны, а вот как правильно и красиво исправить не очень понятно.
Очевидный вариант - рекурсивно пробежаться по словарю и привести все ключи к строкам. Только не хочется городить велосипеды, может кто-нибудь уже решал такую проблему более элегантно?

вроде бы, элегантнее этого: print(json.dumps(sorted({1: 1, '2': '2'}.items(), key=lambda x: str(x), reverse=True))) вряд ли получится

@strawdog тут еще проблема, что такой код не зайдет в вложенные списки/словари(

Тут два варианта - рекурсивно ключи к строкам привести, или рекурсивно отсортировать словари (со своей функцией key, как в примере strawdog). Вроде бы первый вариант более простой.

Красиво — в принципе изначально не допускать попадания числовых ключей в словарь, всё остальное костыли

Кроме того, смешивание чисел и строк в ключах может случайно привести к проблемам подобным этой https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1005005

@andreymal а почему числа как ключи в словаре это плохо? За исключением возникающих проблем с json.dumps

@rew поэтому и плохо, других причин вроде нет

JSON работает только со строками в ключах словарей. Питон допускает числа в качестве расширения. Числа при сохранении преобразуются в строки. sort_keys ошибается для разнотиповых ключей - вероятно это баг. Более "нормальная" реализция могла бы преобразовать все ключи в строки, удалить возникшие дубли, отсортировать строки.

https://bugs.python.org/issue25457

Просто рекурсивно обойти и не мучиться:
import json

def keys_to_string(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        return {str(k): keys_to_string(v) for k, v in d.items()}
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        return [keys_to_string(i) for i in d]
    return d

data = {'2': 1, 1: '2', 6: {'4': 4, 5: 5}, '3': [6, 7, {8: '8'}]}

string_data = keys_to_string(data)

json_string = json.dumps(string_data, sort_keys=True, indent=2)
print(json_string)

Вывод:
{
  "1": "2",
  "2": 1,
  "3": [
    6,
    7,
    {
      "8": "8"
    }
  ],
  "6": {
    "4": 4,
    "5": 5
  }
}

[Program finished]


Надо добавлять префикс если тип int, тогда будет работать корректно.

При сериализации всё равно останется только  "1": "val_2", так что ваш пример надуманный. А если это изначально критично, то товарищ andreymal уже на эту тему в комментариях высказался выше.

Вам надо совсем немного исправить свой ответ, и он будет исчерпывающим. Т.к. в вопросе пытаются сериализировать немного "нестабильный" при сериализации словарь.

Можно прогнать первый этап без сортировки:
normalized = json.loads(json.dumps({1: 1, '2': '2'}))

а затем уже:
json.dumps(normalized, sort_keys=True)


Здесь та же проблема, что и в ответе @Amgarak. При normalized = json.loads(json.dumps({1: 1, '2': '2', 2: '22'})) - вывод: {"1": 1, "2": "22"}

@AnnaBazueva-SPAM В некоторых случаях разделение ключей 1 и "1" может быть нежелательно, например при обмене данными с JavaScript (там эти ключи тождественны).

Я писала в комментарии к ответу @Amgarak , что надо добавлять префиксы. Просто ваши ответы поверхностные, т.к. в вопросе пытаются сериализовать "нестабильный" при сериализации словарь.
Я поставила Вам минус, а другому ответу плюс (его можно исправить).

Если вы разбираетесь в JavaScript может сможете ответить на мой вопрос ?

@AnnaBazueva-SPAM Прежде всего надо разобраться в источнике нестабильности. Конечно, самое правильное решение - это изначально не допускать такое дублирование, но мы не всегда можем это осуществить. Вопрос Ваш обязательно посмотрю, но не обещаю что скоро.

Конечно, как будет время. Спасибо!

@Spatz, "там эти ключи тождественны". JSON хранит ключи только в виде строк. Этот ответ самый простой и правильный.
